# Scala сделать вывод списком

Tags: scala

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    def checkerFunction(list: List[String], numberToCheck: Int): List[Int] = {

      @scala.annotation.tailrec
      def recursiveFunction(listOfIndex: List[Int], listToCheck: List[String], index: Int): List[Int] = {
        if (listToCheck.isEmpty) listOfIndex
        else {
          val newIndexList =
            if (listToCheck.head == numberToCheck.toString) listOfIndex :+ index;
            else listOfIndex
          recursiveFunction(newIndexList, listToCheck.tail, index + 1)
        }
      }

      recursiveFunction(List(), list, 0)
    }

    val ls = List("1", "2", "1", "3", "1", "0")
    checkerFunction(ls, 1).foreach(println)
  }
}
```

Добрый день, необходимо вывести список из значений. Подскажите пожалуйста, ничего умного в голову не приходит. Задача такова:
 - Нужно написать это рекурсивно, задание заключается в том, чтобы вывести индекс всех вхождений элемента 
   в списке, вывод тоже в список, желательно работать с числами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать pattern matching (три случая: 1) головной элемент списка совпадает с нужным числом, 2) не совпадает, 3) пустой список) и передавать пополняемый список (accumulator) как аргумент рекурсивной функции.

```
def checkerFunction(list: List[Int], numberToCheck: Int): List[Int] = {

  def recursiveFunction(listToCheck: List[Int],
                        index: Int, accumulator: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
    listToCheck match {
      case head :: tail if head == numberToCheck =>
        recursiveFunction(tail, index + 1, index +: accumulator)
      case _ :: tail => recursiveFunction(tail, index + 1, accumulator)
      case Nil => accumulator.reverse
    }
  }

  recursiveFunction(list, 0, Nil)
}
```

Список индексов формируется в обратном порядке и в конце разворачивается. Это эффективнее, чем добавление в конец

```
accumulator :+ index // так лучше не делать
...
case Nil => accumulator
```

Для полноты картины, вот как задачу можно решить стандартными средствами:

```
val indexlist = listToCheck.zipWithIndex.filter(p => p._1 == numberToCheck).map(p => p._2)
```

`zipWithIndex` формирует список кортежей вида `(элемент_списка, номер_в_списке)`, далее фильтруются кортежи, где элемент равен `numberToCheck`, потом из отфильтрованного списка кортежей берём вторые элементы (номера в исходном списке).

Comment: `for ((x, i) <- list.zipWithIndex if x == numberToCheck) yield i` в копилку "стандартных средств"

Comment: Да, можно использовать синтаксис [for comprehension](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html#translating-for-comprehensions).

Answer (score 0):

```
println(checkerFunction(ls, 1))
```

Вот так